# Modify parallel source to work with /dev/usb/lp0 instead of base I/O address 0x378

Tags: parallel-port

I have a very old MP3 player called a Diamond Rio.  It has a parallel interface with a 25 pin parallel adapter.  The Debian package rio looks like it would work to communicate with the device (https://packages.debian.org/sid/rio) but it is hard coded to use old style base I/O addresses 0x278, 0x378.

I have no computers left with a dedicated parallel port.  I've purchased a USB to parallel adapter but the device shows up as /dev/usb/lp0.

Is there a straight forward way to modify the rio program (i have the source) to interact with the new /dev/tty/lp0 device rather than the now non-existant hard-coded register addresses of 0x278, 0x378?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a [shim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)) in the code. Change the definitions of `OUTPORT` and `INPORT` in rio.cpp so that they point to your override functions.

Writing to the BASE_PORT (0x378 by default) can be as simple as writing to the usb emulated device.

But reading the status port (data is received from the device to the host one nibble at a time, check rio.txt for all the details) can be trickier, as the actual parallel port status might be (re)interpreted by the usb adapter. And you still have find out out to access the control port. Adapters are made for printing, not for bit-banging.

An alternative can be a PCI parallel port card.

Or add another layer, say an Arduino and go program->USB->Arduino->Parallel. Since the arduino would only be passing around bytes, depending on how you connect it, the Firmadata library could be enough (no programming on the Arduino). But even if it isn't, the program you'd have to write for the Arduino would be pretty simple.

There used to be DB25 shields for Arduino, you might get lucky and find one. But an Arduino + [DB25 breakout](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32918829227.html) woud work just as well, and allow you to prototype.

That would be my suggestion, a shim on rio's source code for `OUTPUT` and `INPORT`, that communicates with an Arduino over USB, which in turn reads/write the parallel lines directly.

Comment: I think this is a good approach.  I'm going to try this first rather than try to negotiate the USB code.  I've got a breakout board on order.

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically have to reimplement all the communication stack, then. The kinds of things you do to a IBM PC parallel port controller by writing to some addresses simply do not work for the controller in the USB device – nor is that controller a memory-mapped device.

In all honesty: Learn how the rio's protocol works from the code. Replace all places where the code directly writes to the memory of the controller by code that does the right thing with /dev/usb/lp0; it's the only way. The linux kernel documents the lp interface, so it's not *that* hard, but you'll probably have to figure out the right `ioctl`s on your own.

Haven't used that myself (never needed it), but [libieee1284](http://cyberelk.net/tim/libieee1284/interface/) might make that easier, and is easily installable from your favourite OS's package manager.

Generally, after you've done that, not *that* much is left of the existing code, looking at rio.cpp. This code simply makes assumptions on PC hardware that aren't true anymore. In return, by actually using Linux' LP-port driver infrastructure, you'll make sure the same program runs on your x86 PC, on your linux-running macbook, your android phone (assuming that kernel has lp enabled, but I could actually imagine that being the case), and your RaspberryPi: it runs on Linux, no longer only on IBM PC hardware.

Is this worth it? Probably not. The parallel-port era MP3 players sound terrible, both because their chips can't even deal with acceptable MP3 bitrates (can you imagine 64 kb/s stereo used to be "high quality"? Makes me shudder. The best these things can do is 128 kb/s, which is still rather... bad.), and because the amount of memory inside wouldn't hold acceptable-quality audio in relevant amounts. Not that you'd ever want to transfer relevant amounts of data via parallel port! 
They eat batteries for breakfast, and their user interface is very rudimentary.

Now, I'm almost certain you're not doing this because this is the only MP3 player you can afford; you already afforded a USB-LPT adapter, and that's typically at least as expensive as a "new" MP3 player (even if these have become pretty obsolete themselves).
You are thus likely doing it for historical or nostalgia reasons, so who am I to judge.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I will look into lpt programming to get this working.  I think this could be a decent summer programming project to do with my son.  Yes, of course there are many much better options for MP3 players.  I'm interested in getting this thing working just for the sake of getting it working.  I suppose an additional added benefit would be cross platform use for any other people who may be interested in using a USB > Parallel adapter in the future.

Comment: well, only for these who would want to use it to talk to a Rio player of olde, but a fine project nonetheless! I think libieee1284 actually works on more than just linux, so you might even lay the foundation for (post-Win98) windows users, and netbsd users, and err, yeah, seriously, cool project, but let's not assume it will be in high public demand. That doesn't diminish the fun you might have!